# How to create a new dataframe using a specified column in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this Youtube channels dataset from kaggle wherein i want to create a new dataframe which has category_name as music only.
here's the original dataframe--

```
df = pd.read_csv('channels.csv')
df.head(3)
```

the output for this is

```
category_id category_name   channel_id  country description followers   join_date   location    picture_url profile_url title   trailer_title   trailer_url videos
0   24  Entertainment   UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw    United States   I make videos.  69896406    2010-04-29  NaN https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAztY6oYWZnS1Cae9...   http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24...   PewDiePie   bitch lasagna   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dh-RL__uN4 3649
1   10  Music   UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA    India   \   69471946    2006-03-13  NaN https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAxPfKnfHAnAs0rOq...   http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-...   T-Series    Guru Randhawa: GOLIMAAR Lyrical Video | Bhusha...   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ1f44JvlC8 12820
2   24  Entertainment   UCIwFjwMjI0y7PDBVEO9-bkQ    NaN Help change the world. OUR album \'Purpose\' o...   41858494    2007-01-15  NaN https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAzY-4LlEPxP9YOux...   http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIwFjwMjI0y7PD...   Justin Bieber   DJ Khaled - No Brainer (Official Video) ft. Ju...   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxloC1MKTpg 132
```

I wanted to create a new dataframe wherein I only want to store the values having category_name = Music.
I've tried using the groupby and apply functions however didn't  get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use boolean slicing.

```py
is_music = df['category_name'] == 'Music'
new_df = df[is_music]
```

This works because `is_music` is a boolean array that indicates whether a the `category_name` column of a row equals `Music`. In the three-row example you have above, `is_music` would look something like

```py
>>> is_music
0    False
1    True
2    False
```

Then, we can use this information to select only the rows of the data frame where `is_music` is `True`. This is what the second line of code is achieving. Of course, you could just write all of this in one line as well:

```py
new_df = df[df['category_name'] == 'Music']
```